# Infinitely many algebraic fibers implies density

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let $\phi:X\to B^n$ be a proper holomorphic submersion where $B^n$ is the $n$-dimensional complex unit ball.

If there is infinitely many points $p\in B^n$ such that $\phi^{-1}(p)$ is algebraic are they dense in $B^n$?